# How to use several viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have problem concerning viewcontrollers. I have done some iphone games with just one 
viewcontroller, but now I want to use several. 
I have a MainViewController that creates two viewcontrollers called StageViewController (where the gameplay takes place) and a MenuViewController (where you select the stage you want to play).

My MenuViewController creates buttons from a custom button-class based on UIImageView. And this works fine. The problem is that when I press a button in the Menu I want to call a method in the MainViewController that inactivates the MenuViewController and activates the StageViewController.

What is the best way to do this? I don't want to use Interface Builder, just code.

Answer (score 0):

did you read [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)?
If not do so now, especially the section about Navigation Controllers

Comment: Yes I read a bit of that article but I don't want to use the Navigation Toolbar with the Back-button and so forth. I want to make a fullscreen application with custom buttons. Do I still use UINavigationController?